# XMLHttpRequest - sending arrays by _POST

Tags: arrays, post, xmlhttprequest

With the old $.ajax method I would send arrays and normal data like so:

```
var dataARR = {
    byteValue: 1,
    data: []
};
```

**Note `data` is an array.**

```
dataARR.data.push({Username: "wazo", Info: "wazoinfo"});
dataARR.data.push({Username: "bifo", Info: "bifoinfo"});
```

Then getting it ready and sending:

```
var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(dataARR);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", // This for array
    url: "login.php",
    cache: false,
    data: { myJson: dataJSON },
    success: function (data) {
        // Do stuff here
    }
});
```

In the php code I would then do the following:

```
$dataTotal = json_decode($post['myJson'], true);
$Username0 = $dataTotal['data'][0]['Username'];
$Info0 = $dataTotal['data'][0]['Info']);
$Username1 = $dataTotal['data'][1]['Username'];
$Info1 = $dataTotal['data'][1]['Info']);
```

All that worked well.

However, now I am changing to XMLHttpRequest:

```
var url = "login.php";
var method = "POST";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
} else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
} else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
}

if (!xhr) {
    return;
}
// Response handlers.
xhr.onload = function (data) {
    // Do stuff
};
```

And the important bit

```
var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(dataARR);
xhr.send({ myJson: dataJSON });
```

**But now the `$_POST['myJson']` does not exist**

When I do an `echo print_r($_POST);`, it returns `Array()1`

**Question: What do I need to send in `xhr.send(????);` to get it so I can read the arrays in php again?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access the data differently with XMLHttpRequest.

In the javascript:

```
var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(dataARR);
xhr.send(dataJSON);
```

In the php:

```
$dataTotal = json_decode(file_get_contents( "php://input" ), true);
$Username0 = $dataTotal['data'][0]['Username'];
$Info0 = $dataTotal['data'][0]['Info']);
$Username1 = $dataTotal['data'][1]['Username'];
$Info1 = $dataTotal['data'][1]['Info']);
```